# Java find and display row of 2D array that has JComboBox selected word

Tags: arrays, 2d

I have a text file that reads into 2D fixed size array.

Example:

```
first    2   33   44   55
second   4   55   67    2
third   22   33    5   55
fourth   3   76   69   14
fifth   23   54   67    7
```

I also have JComboBox which contains names of each row (first, second, third, fourth, fifth).

I need to display row based on JComboBox selection with smallest value in it (only smallest value no row name).

I can read text into 2D array and display it.
I can find the row with the matching word.
However, it only displays matching word instead of the whole row. 
How can I do the last part of my problem that displays row with smallest value?

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        // JComboBox selection
        String jCBoxSelectedWord = JComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String strLine;
          int arraySize = 51;
          String [][]array = new String[arraySize][];
          int index = 0;
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
          { 
           array[index] = strLine.split(" ");
           index++;            
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
          {
              if(array[i] != null) 
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) 
                  {
                      if(array[i][j].equals(jCBoxSelectedWord))
                      {
                          System.out.print(array[i][j]); // <-- only displays one word
                      }
                  }
                  System.out.println("");                 
              }
          }
```

Comment: Can anybody help me with the solution?